# Can interaction free measurement of some kind make it possible to measure 0 K?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

Many of the answers to the question "Is it possible to obtain 0 K" state that we can never know if we ever reached 0 K because the act of measurement will impart some energy to it causing it to change its temperature.

But while reading over Elitzur–Vaidman bombs, I learned that interaction free measurements can be made.

So, is it possible to measure 0 K (even theoretically) from such kinds of experiments?

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester#Many-worlds_interpretation)